# Low search - match two grid fields (AND)?

Tags: low-search

I want to use low search to filter entries that matches two grid fields.

Example Grid:

```
first_name    age
John          14
Leon          15
```

When I submit a form where I search for first_name=John and age between 10 and 20, I only want entries that contains grid rows that matches both John and the age (not OR).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Low Search does support searching for values that fall within ranges, but it looks like you would need to do a bit of template work to get it to work with your example.  Check out the documentation [here](https://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#ranges).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although, the question is if I can match both of the grid fields at the same time.

For example, an entry with only one grid row (Leon, 14) should not match in the example above since the first_name isn't John (but the age is within range).